# How to create an image of a triangle with sides and angles

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

Just as the question says, how do i create an image file of a triangle in which the sides and the angles are inputted.

The current solution i am using is with turtle library

```
forward(s1)
left(180-c)
forward(s2)
left(180-a)
forward(s3)
ts = turtle.getcanvas()
ts.postscript(file="file.ps")
```

Now this works, but it outputs the image in a ps file. Since i want it in a image form(like png/jpg/pil image), i need to convert it to it. So i found that to do that you can use

```
img = Image.open("file.ps")
img.save("file.png")
```

But that says it "unable to locate Ghostscript on paths"
But since i cannot install ghostscript(Due to reasons) on my device, i cant convert it to am image form.
So my question is, is there any library or any way to create an image file of a triangle using just the sides and angles.
No idea how i could do it in PIL, as i need coordinates for the vertices, and i have no clue how to get the coordinates of the vertices. Also another problem with Turtle is that it creates a new window to make the image. So preferably, i want the image creation to happen in the background. Any way to do this?

Edit: Code i am currently using to make the file:

```
def trianglesss(s1,s2,s3):
    a = s1
    b = s2
    c = s3
    a1 = round(math.degrees(math.acos(((b**2)+(c**2)-(a**2))/(2*b*c))))
    b1 = round(math.degrees(math.acos(((c**2)+(a**2)-(b**2))/(2*a*c))))
    c1 = round(math.degrees(math.acos(((b**2)+(a**2)-(c**2))/(2*a*b))))
    turtle.tracer(0,0)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.speed('fastest')
    hideturtle()
    forward(s1)
    left(180-c1)
    forward(s2)
    left(180-a1)
    forward(s3)
    turtle.update()
    ts = turtle.getcanvas()
    ts.postscript(file="file.eps")
    bye()
    trisssimg = Image.open("file.eps")
    trisssimg.save("Trisss.jpg")
trianglesss(20,20,20)
#Calculating angles using the formula from:
#https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-solving-sss-triangles.html
```

Comment: Please provide a more complete turtle graphic drawing code.

Comment: OK, that's close enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Image and ImageDraw to draw line on image.
Here, follow part of the turtle concept to give command to draw lines.

```py
from math import cos, sin, pi, ceil
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

def draw(commands, filename=None, size=None, show=True):

    x0, y0 = 0, 0
    direction = 0
    line_width, line_color = 1, 'black'
    pen_down = False
    points = []

    for command, value in commands:
        cmd = command.strip().lower()
        if cmd == "color":
            line_color = value
        elif cmd == "width":
            line_width = value
        elif cmd in ("forward", "fd", "backward", "bk"):
            distance = value
            radian = direction/180*pi if cmd in ("forward", "fd") else (direction+180)/180*pi
            x1, y1 = x0 + distance * cos(radian), y0 + distance * sin(radian)
            if pen_down:
                points.append([(x0, y0), (x1, y1), line_color, line_width])
            x0, y0 = x1, y1
        elif cmd == "left":
            direction -= value
        elif cmd == "right":
            direction += value
        elif cmd in ("penup", "pu"):
            pen_down = False
        elif cmd in ("pendown", "pd"):
            pen_down = True

    xs, ys = [], []
    for point1, point2, color, width in points:
        xs += [point1[0], point2[0]]
        ys += [point1[1], point2[1]]
    x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max = min(xs), max(xs), min(ys), max(ys)
    w, h = ceil(x_max - x_min + 1), ceil(y_max - y_min + 1)

    width, height = size if size else (w, h)
    dx, dy = (width - w)/2 - x_min, (height - h)/2 - y_min
    im = Image.new(mode="RGBA", size=(width, height), color=(0, 0, 0, 0))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im, mode="RGBA")

    for point1, point2, line_color, line_width in points:
        p1, p2 = (point1[0]+dx, point1[1]+dy), (point2[0]+dx, point2[1]+dy)
        draw.line([p1, p2], fill=line_color, width=line_width)
    if filename:
        im.save(filename)
    if show:
        im.show()

commands = [("PenDown", None), ("Width", 5), ("Color", "blue"),
    ("FD", 100), ("Left", 120), ("FD", 100), ("left", 120), ("FD", 100)]

draw(commands, "Triangle.png", (200, 200))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since the `turtle` module is based on `tkinter`, you can do it with the PIL something like the following.

```
import math
from PIL import ImageGrab
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox as tkMessageBox
from tkinter.constants import *
import turtle

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 500, 400
IMG_FILENAME = 'turtlescreen.png'  # Extension determines file format.

def trianglesss(t, s1, s2, s3):
    a = s1
    b = s2
    c = s3
    a1 = round(math.degrees(math.acos(((b**2)+(c**2)-(a**2)) / (2*b*c))))
    b1 = round(math.degrees(math.acos(((c**2)+(a**2)-(b**2)) / (2*a*c))))
    c1 = round(math.degrees(math.acos(((b**2)+(a**2)-(c**2)) / (2*a*b))))
    t.pendown()
    t.forward(s1)
    t.left(180-c1)
    t.forward(s2)
    t.left(180-a1)
    t.forward(s3)

def draw_stuff(canvas):
    screen = turtle.TurtleScreen(canvas)
    t = turtle.RawTurtle(screen.getcanvas())
    t.speed(0)  # Fastest.
    t.pencolor('black')
    t.hideturtle()
    trianglesss(t, 200, 200, 200)

def image_grab(root, widget):
    x = root.winfo_rootx() + widget.winfo_x()
    y = root.winfo_rooty() + widget.winfo_y()
    x1 = x + widget.winfo_width()
    y1 = y + widget.winfo_height()
    return ImageGrab.grab().crop((x, y, x1, y1))

def save_file(root, canvas, filename):
    """ Convert the Canvas widget into an image file. """
    # Get image of Canvas and save it to a file.
    img = image_grab(root, canvas)
    img.save(IMG_FILENAME)  # Save image file.

    tkMessageBox.showinfo("Info", "Image saved as %r" % filename, parent=root)


# Main
root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT,
                   borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()

btn_frame = tk.Frame(root)
btn_frame.pack()
btn1 = tk.Button(btn_frame, text='Draw', command=lambda: draw_stuff(canvas))
btn1.pack(side=LEFT)
btn2 = tk.Button(btn_frame, text='Save',
                 command=lambda: save_file(root, canvas, IMG_FILENAME))
btn2.pack(side=LEFT)
btn3 = tk.Button(btn_frame, text='Quit', command=root.quit)
btn3.pack(side=LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot of it running:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you, it works. Also i removed the buttons for drawing and saving and just call the drawing and saving functions in the main, as i want this to be automated. Can you tell how to do the quit command after the drawing and saving? As the button works, but i want it to automatically quit after drawing and saving. Again thanks for the help.

Comment: Also, is it possible to do the saving work and the creation of the triangle in the background? Thanks

Comment: You can call `root.quit()` to terminate the `mainloop()`. I don't think you can create the triangle in the background, although I'm not completely sure what you mean. This works by taking a screenshot of the drawing made by `turtle`, so the screen has to be visible.